# Evaluating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(n x-\frac{x^2}{2}) \sin(2 \pi x)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I want to evaluate the following integral ($n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$):
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(n x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \sin(2 \pi x)\ dx$$
Maple and WolframAlpha tell me that this is zero and I also hope it is zero, but I don't see how I can argue for it.

I thought of rewriting the sine via $\displaystyle \sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ or using Euler's identity on $\exp(n x-\frac{x^2}{2})$. However, in both ways I am stuck...

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$I = \frac{e^{n^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi x) \, dx \stackrel{x = x-n}{=} \frac{e^{n^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi x) \, dx$$

Now divide the integral into two parts:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi x) \, dx$$
Take one of them and substitute $t=-x$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi x) \, dx = -\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi t) \, dt$$
Because these integrals are finite, i.e.:
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \left| e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \sin (2\pi t) \right| \, dt \le \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \, dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
We can write $I = 0$ and we are not dealing with any kind of indeterminate form like $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: The first line is essentially enough since the integrand on the right is odd. There's no convergence issue since $e^{-{x^2 \over 2}} \leq e^{-|x|}$ for $|x| > 2$ for example and the exponential function has finite integral.

Comment: @AndreasS I'm pinging you on behalf of Zarrax in case you haven't seen his comment.

Comment: @MattN. Thanks. I saw the comment. However, I think qogosz made the steps more explicit (However, it works well with any odd function). And Zarrax also cares about the convergence - otherwise he wouldn't have to argue about it.

Comment: @AndreasS Good then : ) Just wanted to make sure since he didn't ping you.

Comment: I think the first line is not enough until you show the integral is finite. This is because $I$ is an improper integral and the $x$ variable can approach to $\pm\infty$ independently.